# Does the heating of a wire depend on the frequency of current flowing through it?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, electric-circuits

Does heating of a wire only depend on how much current is flowing through it, or does it also depend on the frequency of that current (if it is AC)? If so, what is the relationship between frequency and heating?

Thanks!

Comment: Depends on how you model a wire. If pure resistance, then it does not depend on the frequency (depends on the RMS value). If you have reactive impedances like capacitors and inductors, then yes, it depends on the frequency because the impedance itself depends on the frequency of the supply.

Comment: A reasonable question, since higher frequency does  mean more energy in waves, but did you try some research?  Google about root-mean-squared current.

Comment: Inductive or capacitive reactance in a circuit are frequency dependent and will reduce the amount of current  in phase with the voltage.  However, the energy dissipated as heat by the in-phase current is still not frequency dependent.

Comment: Higher frequency waves, do  not have more energy in general. This is completely false.

Answer (score 3):

Heating of the wire can indeed significantly depend on the frequency of the current due to the skin effect, among other things. Skin effect causes an increase of the effective resistance of the wire as the current flows closer to the periphery of the wire at higher frequency.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the heating of a metal or resistor depends on frequency. There are many types of resistors. Metal oxide, metal foil, high power (2W ~ 10W), etc...
All resistor have properties like temperature coefficient of resistance (TCR), which is gives an idea of how the resistor value will change with the temperature conditions. Usually, the analog resistor is placed at room temperature. So in that case, you might think that resistor with good TCR will not change with the room temperature, that is right. But it can changes according to the AC input power on this resistor.

Usually, TCR is about 0.01 ppm/K to typically 100 ppm/K. If you flow a AC current on a resistor $I=I_o \sin(\omega t)$ , due to Corbino effect, you get a third harmonic voltage V3w that contains informations on how the wire is heated and it depends on the frequency.

$R = R_o[1+a(T-T_o)]$. The power is $P = RI^2$ at $2\omega$ so the elevation of temperature on the resistor is also at $2\omega$ (harmonic 2). Now the voltage is $V = RI$, which is the product of a 2w signal with $1\omega$ signal, like $\sin(2\omega t)\sin(\omega t)$, so you get a $3\omega$ signal that you can detect with a lock in amplifier, with the reference to the input 1w signal of the current source.  Therefore you can monitor the heating of a wire as a function of frequency, by detecting the $3\omega$ (third harmonic) of your signal with a lock in amplifier.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Due to the skin effect heating (power $P$ dissipated in the wire) depends on frequency, but not in a simple or linear way. As long as the skin depth is larger that the radius of the wire, you see almost no effect. When the skin depth gets smaller than about 50% of the radius, but not being super small, $P(f)$ is proportional to $\sqrt{f}$. At super small skin depths $P(f)$ should be proportional to $f$.

Answer (score -1):

Ideally speaking, yes and no.  If you mean the average, no it wouldn't change with the frequency, but if you want the instantaneous heat,  then yes it totally depends on the frequency of the current. But in the real world you're usually concerned with the average, so it wouldn't matter.

#### MATH

Ideally speaking, a wire is not supposed to drop a voltage, but the real world is more fickle than a cat, so let's say it drops a small voltage, ie, let's model it as a resistor.
Then the equation would be-
$$VI = P$$
$$V = V_o\cos(\omega t)$$
$$I = \frac{V_o}{R}\cos(\omega t)$$
*Simply multiply to get the answer*
$$P = \frac{1}{R}V_o^2\cos^2(\omega t)$$
This, you see, is the instantaneous power, but when we're in the real world, instantaneous power is pretty much useless in this case, so we use the average power-

$$P_{avg} = \frac{1}{T}\int^\pi_0 P.d(\omega t)$$
And since I'm too lazy, I won't do much further, but what you should know is that it's constant. (It doesn't contain $\omega$) So it doesn't depend on the frequency

Comment: You might want to clarify and substantiate your answer.

Comment: I was about to upvote this as the correct answer (at least, as far as the basic physics goes)... but the last equation contains many typos and we are dealing here with a trivial integral...

Comment: I haven't done the math. However I think that depending on what you define V to be, you've made an error. Given V is what you've described as the TOTAL emf in the circuit, then it's right. However given V is the pd supplied by the battery, then you are ignoring the inductance emf. Which should be $\epsilon_{wire} = [V-L\frac{dI}{dt}]$  ohms law is also not valid here since V is changing in time. You need to use the complex ohms law! [Or with the case of inductance , take the real part and work with purely real values]